# Haskell: A problem with the simplest wai example

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie, and I'm trying to get the wai package working (because I'm interested in using Haskell for web applications). I tried to start with the first, simplest example from the [wai](http://github.com/snoyberg/wai) homepage:

```
[ 1] {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
[ 2] import Network.Wai
[ 3] import Network.Wai.Enumerator (fromLBS)
[ 4] import Network.Wai.Handler.SimpleServer (run)
[ 5] 
[ 6] app :: Application
[ 7] app _ = return Response
[ 8]     { status          = status200
[ 9]     , responseHeaders = [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
[10]     , responseBody    = ResponseLBS "Hello, Web!"
[11]     }
[12] 
[13] main :: IO ()
[14] main = do
[15]     putStrLn $ "http://localhost:8080/"
[16]     run 8080 app
```

When I run the code above (with runhaskell), I get the following error:

wapp.hs:10:36:
    No instance for (Data.String.IsString
    Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)
      arising from the literal `"Hello, Web!"' at wapp.hs:10:36-48

Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
   (Data.String.IsString 
    Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString)

In the first argument of `ResponseLBS', namely`"Hello, Web!"'

In the `responseBody' field of a record

In the first argument of `return', namely

```
`Response
 {status = status200,
  responseHeaders = [("Content-Type", "text/plain")],
  responseBody = ResponseLBS "Hello, Web!"}'
```

Is it something wrong with the example (I don't think so, because it's from the wai homepage - it should be correct!), or is it something wrong with my Haskell system?

Answer (score 7):

You need to import modules that export `IsString` instances for the types you want to use as overloaded strings.  It looks like you're not importing any module that exports an `IsString` instance for lazy bytestrings.  Try adding this import to your code:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After I added the line you suggested, ghc detected ambiguous occurence of putStrLn, so I changed putStrLn in the example to Prelude.putStrLn, and everything started to work :-)

Comment: You could also change the import to import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
(), which would import the instance you need, but none of the conflicting names.

Comment: Note that `Char8` is very unsafe (it assumes you want a Latin1 encoding and corrupts characters that do not fit in that encoding).  It is much safer to explicitly encode strings.

Comment: It actually assumes ASCII, corrupting everything else.  Which is exactly reasonable for ByteString.  If you want unicode, use Text.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `hugs` or `ghc`? At the bottom of the wai webpage is the item titled `Doing without overloaded strings' that seems to address your problem. Try:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB8

notFound = Response
    { status          = Status404
    , responseHeaders = [("Content-Type", B8.pack "text/plain")]
    , responseBody    = Right $ fromLBS $ LB8.pack "404 - Not Found"
    }
```

Comment: I use ghc. I've tried that, but I get the following error:


wapp.hs:12:26:
  Couldn't match expected type `CIByteString'
  against inferred type `[Char]'


  Expected type: ResponseHeader

  Inferred type: [Char]

  In the expression: "Content-Type"

  In the expression: ("Content-Type", B8.pack "text/plain")