# Unable to do pattern matching on Word8

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, servant

In my Servant/Wai app I want to redict all the requests from "domain.com" to "www.domain.com"

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
--.......

app :: Application
app req respond = do
  case requestHeaderHost req of
    Just host -> do
      case BS.unpack host of
        "www":rest -> respond =<< redirect' HttpTp.status302 [] "domain.com"

      _ -> undefined

    Nothing -> undefined
```

The error is

```
No instance for (Data.String.IsString GHC.Word.Word8)
  arising from the literal ‘"www"’
In the pattern: "www"
```

I know what it means and I think that the class Show should've have been implemented for Word8 and if not there must be a reason. Maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?

How can I fix this or do it another better way?

Update:

I can't get it to compile:

```
-- 1
Just host -> do
  case BS.isPrefixOf (BS.pack $ show "www") host of 

-- 2
Just host -> do
  case Text.isPrefixOf (Text.pack $ show "www") host of 

-- 3
Just host -> do
  case DL.isPrefixOf  "www" host of
```

There's always type mismatch.

Comment: Maybe this will help (if it does, keep in mind that pasting error messages into Google search can produce wonders): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753445/haskell-a-problem-with-the-simplest-wai-example

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `"www":rest` implies the type `[[Char]]`, while you need `[Char]`. Here's what your pattern should be:

```
'w':'w':'w':rest
```

Oh. And you should use `Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack` (or `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.unpack`, if it's lazy) to be able to match against characters. Otherwise you need to use the ASCII code of `'w'` instead of the character.

Comment: @user6250601 Seems like your ByteString is strict. Use `Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack` instead of `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.unpack`.

Comment: @user6250601 Pay a close attention to the module names and types. The types `Data.ByteString.ByteString` and `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString` are different! Your errors are caused by you using the `Data.ByteString.Lazy` API against a strict bytestring, while only `Data.ByteString` and `Data.ByteString.Char8` are applicable to it.